# MapStruct : Capitalize field after mapping?

Tags: java, spring-boot, automapper, dto, mapstruct

I am new for MapStruct and trying to learn some functionalities. I am trying to  capitalize a title field after mapping from dto to entity. I use the following approach, but ı am not sure if there is already a build function that can be used directly without creating a new method with `@AfterMapping`:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface RecipeRequestMapper {

    RecipeRequestMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(RecipeRequestMapper.class);

    Recipe toEntity(RecipeRequest dto);

    RecipeRequest toDto(Recipe entity);

    @AfterMapping
    default void getCapitalizedTitle(@MappingTarget Recipe entity, RecipeRequest dto) {
        entity.setTitle(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(dto.getTitle()));
    }
}
```

It seems working, but I want to know if there is a proper way for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [expression](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions) like this:

```java
@Mapping(target = "title", expression = java(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(dto.getTitle()))")
Recipe toEntity(RecipeRequest dto);

@Mapping(target = "title", expression = "java(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(entity.getTitle()))")
RecipeRequest toDto(Recipe entity);
```

Also maybe it is necessary use the full package name:

```java
java(org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils.capitalizeFully(entity.getTitle()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot amigo, wonderful. By the way, do you have any idea about this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75625082/java-stream-check-if-record-exists-and-throw-exception-if-not/75625387#75625387 Any idea please?